# How can I adjust and/or handle unusual character width in web-browsers?

Tags: html, google-chrome, character-encoding

In my Windows 10 (region: Japan, windows display language: Japanese)
I cannot control width of some unusual characters in the following HTML.

`<html lang="en-US"><body><div><pre style="font-family: monospace !important;">
Atom and brackets           M
monospaced or proportional  M
what is                     M
ΔΓΘ≠a                   M
abc                       M
      f                   M
你好안녕こんにちは          M
السلام
</pre></div></body></html>`

Usual characters, latin alphabets and arabic digits, simple punctuators etc are displayed expectedly.

But greek alphabets, greek alphabet delta, greek alphabet gamma, greek alphabet theta, mathematical inequality sign are widen than such usual characters.

And emoticons confuse me too much.

I tried many browsers,

- Google Chrome 69.0 (Japanese mode): greek alphabets and inequality sign are double-sized by latin alphabets. but in developer tool, thats are same width to latin alphabet.
- Google Chrome Canary Version 71.0 (English mode): greek alphabets and inequality sign are same width to latin alphabet expectedly, but still emotioncs are...
- MS IE 11.431: greek alphabets and inequality sign are same width to latin alphabet expectedly, but still emotioncs are...
- Microsoft Edge 41.16299: Like as MS IE but emoticons are full-skined (In MS IE, there are monochromed).
- Firefox 56.0: like as MS Edge.
- Opera 55.0: like as MS Edge.

It's depends on user environment horribly (Especially in Google chrome).

Especially in Google chrome, How can I control the problem without tuning user environment language settings?

image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wry1Y.png)